# Rename column index from 0 to last column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame `dat` as below:

```
        0       1       0       1       0       1
0       A       23      0.1     122     56      9
1       B       24      0.45    564     36      3
2       C       25      0.2     235     87      5
3       D       13      0.8     567     42      6
4       E       5       0.9     356     12      2
```

As you can see from above, the columns' index are 0,1,0,1,0,1 etc. I want to rename back to original index starting from 0,1,2,3,4 ... and I did the following:

```
dat = dat.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The index was not changed. How do I get the index renamed in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat.columns = range(dat.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways:

```
dat =  dat.rename(columns = lambda x: dat.columns.get_loc(x))
```

Or

```
dat = dat.rename(columns = dict(zip(dat.columns, range(dat.shape[1]))))
```

Or

```
dat = dat.set_axis(pd.RangeIndex(dat.shape[1]), axis=1, inplace=False)

Out[677]:
   0   1     2    3   4  5
0  A  23  0.10  122  56  9
1  B  24  0.45  564  36  3
2  C  25  0.20  235  87  5
3  D  13  0.80  567  42  6
4  E   5  0.90  356  12  2
```